# Send sms using perl script

Tags: perl, perl-module, mod-perl

I'm trying to send sms using perl script. I have tried the below modules. Please help me ..

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Net::SMS::160By2;

my $username = "xxxxx";
my $password = "yyyyy";
my $msg = "Hi";
my $to = "zzzzzz";
my $obj = Net::SMS::160By2->new($username, $password);
$obj->send_sms($msg, $to);
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So what's the problem?

Comment: where is $to value coming from?

Answer (score 0):

"Where is $to value coming from?"

You need to create it and provide the phone number hwere the SMS needs to be sent.

```
my $to = "+1 555 4214-4523";
```